# Need to select Null values and not null values in same column using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I need to select all the column by filtering "where speed = "Ten" and Zone in ('Meta','Google') and Zone is null;

But i am getting empty ouptput after running this below query

select * from table_name where speed = "Ten" and Zone in ('Meta','Google') and Zone is null;

Columns: speed,Zone

Comment: `where speed = "Ten" and (Zone in ('Meta','Google') OR Zone is null);`  should it not be OR condition instead of AND ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly. You are trying to find item which has speed of "Ten" and its zone falls into "Google", "Meta" , "". Or Zone is an optional field which could be null?

```
select speed, zone from TABLE_NAME where speed = "TEN" AND zone in ("Google", "Meta" , "")
```

Or

```
select speed, zone from TABLE_NAME where speed = "Ten" and (Zone in ('Meta','Google') OR Zone is null);
```

The problem with your query language is that Zone could not be non-null and null at the same time.